# CSS side by side layout

Tags: css

When I shrink the browser width past a certain point the spec div drops below the main div.  I want to prevent this from happening.  I thought perhaps I could make a div that holds both #main and #spec and set a min-width for it, but that does not seem to work.

```
#main {
clear: both;
width: 400px;
min-width: 400px;
float:left;
padding: 10px; 
}

#spec{
padding: 4px;
float: left;
width: 270px;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your suggestion will infact work. You're container divs min width must be at least 698px. Also you don't need a min width on main if you have a static width.

Comment: Min-width should do it... what browser are you targeting?

Comment: I am using Firefox 10, but would like it to be cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this out using min-width and it definitely works. Because the elements are floated they need to be cleared inside the container for it to work.

See the example here, http://jsfiddle.net/3TDNf/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to bet you are running in to an issue with the [CSS Box-Model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

In a nutshell, the box model for some reason, does not include the border or padding, which most people expect that it will (and in fact it used to, further confusing the situation)

I suggest adding the following rule to your CSS:

```
*{
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will cause your web pages to use the border-box style of box model, which means everything except the margin will be counted in the element's width.

Comment: I assume I insert this at the top of the CSS page and the closing brace after all the other code.  When I did this it pulled the #spec div below the #main div even with the browser window fully open.

Comment: No, * is a wildcard selector that adds the style inside to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I could make a div that holds both #main and #spec and set a min-width
>   for it

Yet your posted css shows that you placed the `min-width: 400px;` on the `#main` div. Perhaps you need to move the `min-width:400px;` so that it applies to the div that contains both `#main` and `#spec`.